# Como ajustar altura de elementos da 'sidebar'?

Tags: css

[image: DIV dentro da sidebar]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com esse problema onde algo da "DIV Feed" está ultrapassando o tamanho da sua "DIV pai". Estou disposto a explicar melhor o problema caso necessário.

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
      <ul class="nav nav-stacked feed-adaptation">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><img src="imagens/abc.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TEAM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="container-feed">
          <div class="header-feed">
            <span class="feed-name">FEED</span>
          </div>

          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="imagens/social-icons/facebook.png" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
              <p><b>Phellipe lins</b> citou <a href="#">#abc</a> em um post no facebook.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="imagens/social-icons/twitter.png" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
              <p><b>Phellipe lins</b> citou <a href="#">#abc</a> em um post no facebook.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="imagens/social-icons/facebook.png" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
              <p><b>Phellipe lins</b> citou <a href="#">#abc</a> em um post no facebook.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="conteudo">
        <h1 class="home-text title"><b>/</b>Hello word</b></h1>
        <p class="home-text">subtitle</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.col-md-2.text-center {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    height: 100%;
}

.thumbnail {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
    height: auto;
}

.container {
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Por favor inclua os trechos de código relevantes na pergunta (HTML e/ou CSS). Quanto à pergunta, acho que entendi qual é seu problema, mas se puder explicar um pouquinho melhor seria interessante sim. :) (tipo: o problema é que o leiaute "global" está com problemas - aquela barra branca na primeira imagem? o problema é que o feed está exigindo *scrolling*? etc)

Comment: códigos adicionados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A princípio, parece que basta colocar uma regra `overflow: hidden` no "DIV pai". Mas isso irá "cortar o excedente", ocultando parte da "DIV filha".

Experimente remover a regra `height: 100%` do "DIV pai".

Na verdade, talvez seja melhor remover todos os `height` do seu código CSS. Eu não faria modificações em `.row` e `.container`, classes fundamentais do Bootstrap...

E ao invés de alterar a classe do Bootstrap `.col-md-2.text-center`, eu criaria uma classe com outro nome, para aplicar ao "DIV pai".

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-2 text-center navegacao">
```

CSS

```
.col-md-2.text-center.navegacao {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}

.thumbnail {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Resolve em partes... Queria mesmo que todo meu "container" crescesse junto com essa 'sidebar' e não ficasse essa barra branca. :(

Comment: Cara, é por isso que é importante explicar bem o problema... Tô aqui há meia hora "explorando" as diferentes opções, mas sem saber exatamente o que você quer fica difícil, né? Sugiro editar a pergunta, esclarecendo que: a) você **não quer** evitar que o sidebar cresça; b) você quer que a div "maiorzona" (e não aquela marcada no screenshot 2) acompanhe o sidebar.

Comment: Phellipe, agora que estou entendendo melhor o problema, acrescentei outra alternativa na resposta. Por favor, verifique se funciona.

Comment: Foi mal, @mgibsonbr. Tenho que melhorar meu português. Se serve de 'desculpas', sua didática é exemplar.

Comment: Errr, oque eu faria pra deixar que a classe ao lado cresça de acordo com a sidebar? remover os atributos height dos elementos não funcionou bem...

Comment: Phellipe, veja a resposta aceita para a seguinte questão: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height

Answer (score 0):

Não consegui reproduzir seu problema exatamente como seu código está (altura expressa em porcentagem - mas com altura em pixels [o problema aparece](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/JFR8U/)), mas me parece que sua causa é o fato de você ter atribuído uma altura explícita para a div pai (`.col-md-2.text-center`) mas não para a div filha (`.container-feed`). Nesse caso, ela cresce além dos limites do contêiner, e por padrão fica visível além desses limites.

Se você adicionar uma regra de `overflow` na div pai, entretanto, a div filha vai parar de se exceder além desses limites, e se comportar segundo a regra especificada (exceto `overflow: none`, que é o mesmo que não ter essa regra). Usando `overflow: hidden` por exemplo, como sugeriro por @J. Bruni, [vai fazer com que o excesso seja "descartado"](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/JFR8U/1/), o que pode ou não ser o que você quer (as bordas inferiores, por exemplo, ficarão invisíveis, e qualquer conteúdo parcial ficará da mesma forma inacessível). Usando `overflow: scroll` ou `overflow: auto` [permitiria que você rolasse a div pai inteira](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/JFR8U/2/) - o que pode ser meio "esquisito"...

Se não estiver satisfeito com essas soluções, sugiro atribuir explicitamente a altura da div filha. Assim, ela não excederá a altura do contêiner, e você ainda pode atribuir uma regra de *scrolling* para ela somente, se assim o desejar. [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/JFR8U/3/).

Comment: Bem conveniente seu exemplo. Irei adota-lo! Valeu!
<br/>
Edição: A solução/exemplo é bem inconfortável numa tela de 320x480. Vou ver como desenrolo. :L

Comment: @PhellipeLins É, o jsFiddle no mobile fica ruim mesmo... Mas se for só para **ver** o exemplo (e não editar) tem um botão do lado do botão "Run" que te dá um link próprio pros dispositivos móveis (ex.: http://jsfiddle.net/m/afy/). Agora, se você estava falando do exemplo em si, de fato só coloquei `300px` de altura para tentar reproduzir o problema, mas a resposta do J. Bruni é mais completa que a minha.

Comment: Ok! Valeu, @mgibsonbr!